# Summernote Angular 6 CLI comments or annotation

Tags: angular6, summernote

Hi i have configured summer note in my Angular 6 app using the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-text-editor',
  templateUrl: './form-text-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-text-editor.component.css']
})
export class FormTextEditorComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private titleService: Title) {  
this.titleService.setTitle( 'Form Text Editor' ); 
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and the html is:

```
<div class="summernote"> </div>
```

It is working successfully. As this text box is going to be edited by multiple users i want to maintain history or annotation. If an user wants to change a particular word, he can add an inline comment or annotation. I know there are text editors capable of this (e.g: etherpad, prosemirror etc) but they are very heavy and dont want all functions. I just need a facility to annotate or add comment.

There is a similar functionality with quill done by someone here: https://codepen.io/sainttushar/pen/yKLdOe

But I want to use summernote to achieve this...is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/lula/ngx-summernote

Use this for Angular 6. I hope this save your time. The documentations is good.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the annotation part included? Because I already installed without any difficulty..

Comment: @doctshinds sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: is it supported in angular 4?